# Remove invalid numbers (too big, too small) from array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of numbers and some numbers are obviously too big or too small relative to them all. I wonder if there is already some kind of function or algorithm that I can use in order to remove these records from array.

Here is an example of array

```
8
7
21
1330829238608
6
7
188
8
25
92433
19
6
```

At the moment all I can think about is just check if number is more than 1k or less than 1k and then do not allow it. But still I get problem since 188 does not belong here either.

Is there any good way that I can get majority of close numbers from this array and produce something like

```
8
7
6
7
8
6
```

This is what I have so far

```
<?php

echo '<pre>';
$startArray = Array(8, 7, 21, 1330829238608, 6, 7, 188, 8, 25, 92433, 19, 6);

print_r($startArray);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($startArray); $i++) {
    if ($i != count($startArray) - 1) {
        if ($startArray[$i] - 10 <= $startArray[$i + 1]) {
            echo $startArray[$i] . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "some numbers are obviously too big or too small" -- how is this obvious?

Comment: how do you define "too big" or "too small"?

Comment: I can't get it. Which numbers are "too big" and "too small"? does it depend on the numbers or is there always the same allowed interval (say 1-100)

Comment: Do you mean relatively too big or too small that other numbers in order, please clearify more

Comment: Calculate the standard deviation of the set and decide upon a distribution that is acceptable (normal should be fine), then throw out any numbers beyond say, 2 standard deviations from the mean in either direction.

Comment: According to this, running the list and throwing away the number you don't want is not an option?

Comment: I think guys, that he is wanting an adaptive 'large' That is, looking at the numbers above, most are grouped around 6-8. Perhaps he wants to smartly strip out the outliers? So if the list is all in the hundreds of thousands, he'd remove a single 3 if it was there, or a single 10,000,000, as it they are way out of the normal range. EDIT: Just as @JohnRasch has stated it. Stats is my weakest math, my apologies.

Comment: @Josh, I agree but there are many ways to define what an outlier is. There is nothing obvious about it. The OP needs to explain more clearly what he wants.

Comment: @BenLee - agreed, even the stdev method won't work with extreme outliers, those would have to be filtered first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be optimized but this is what I figured out, works with diff of 20%, you can change it to whatever % you want, of course.

```
<?php

$startArray = array(8, 7, 21, 1330829238608, 6, 7, 188, 8, 25, 92433, 19, 6);
$groupArray = array();
$startArrayCount = count($startArray);

for ($i = 0; $i < $startArrayCount; $i++) {
    // 20% of current value
    $valueDiff = ($startArray[$i] / 100) * 20;

    // Get minimal and maximal value
    $maxValue = ($startArray[$i] + $valueDiff);
    $minValue = ($startArray[$i] - $valueDiff);

    // Print it out
//    echo 'Diff: ' . $valueDiff . '<br />';
//    echo 'Max: ' . $maxValue . '<br />';
//    echo 'Min: ' . $minValue . '<br />';

    $groupArray[$i] = array();
    for ($n = 0; $n < $startArrayCount; $n++) {
        if ($startArray[$n] <= $maxValue && $startArray[$n] >= $minValue) {
            // echo 'TRUE: ' . $startArray[$n] . '<br />';
            array_push($groupArray[$i], $startArray[$n]);
        }
    }
    //echo '<hr />';
}

// Getting arrays that have most members in it
$max = count($groupArray[0]);
foreach ($groupArray as $group) {
    if (count($group) > $max) {
        $max = count($group);
    }
}

// Taking all those arrays and combining them in one
$finishArray = array();
foreach ($groupArray as $group) {
    if (count($group) == $max) {
        foreach ($group as $key) {
            array_push($finishArray, $key);
        }
    }
}

// Combining all values
$total = null;
foreach ($finishArray as $num) {
    $total = $total + $num;
}

// Getting average
$average = $total / count($finishArray);

echo $average;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
function filter_callback($var){
    return $var < 100 && $var > 2;
}

$array = array(1,1000,23,4453,123,412,321,433,4,6,2,3,5,634,32,432,45,3,4);

$filtered = array_filter($array, "filter_callback");
```

Comment: 100 and 2 is bad for me since it's not adaptable

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrayData = array(8, 7, 21,
                   1330829238608,
                   6, 7, 188, 8, 25,
                   92433,
                   19, 6,
                  );
$min = 7;
$max = 10;

$matches = array_filter( $arrayData,
                         function($data) use ($min,$max) {
                             return (($data >= $min) && ($data <= $max));
                         }
                       );
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Min/Max is bad for me since it's not adaptable

Comment: It probably is, but until you clarify exactly what you need then it's very difficult for us to guess... and you can start by explaining what "adaptable" means to you

Answer (score 0):

I really gotta go but it's an easy one.

1. create a maximum = closest number to 0 in the array, multiplied by $delta.
2. any number in the array smaller than the maximum from pct. 1, but if multiplied by $delta is greater than that maximum, becomes maximum `if($i<$max && $i*$delta>$max) $max = $i*$delta`
3. trim out all numbers bigger than the current maximum.

Problem is you need a $delta. It's safe to go with 2 for delta, but if you want it adaptable don't ask me how to do it because that's cognitive neuroscience.